# PowerBI Embedded API functionality

Tags: azure, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I have some queries about the PowerBI Embedded API, and more so if functionality exists, and if so where can I find it.

In particular, I am looking to find, from the APIs (PowerBI, Embedded or Azure) where I can complete the following functions:

1. View the number of Rendered Views within a Workspace Collection
2. Delete a report/import which has been uploaded
3. Ability to find out how many renders a single report would create - I would find this especially useful given it is billable per render.

Additional functionality I am looking for, is also to be able to save the rendered chart to image or pdf and responsiveness in the dashboards.

I do realise its still in public preview, however, has anyone managed to find the above functionality within the current APIs. 
Thanks
David

Comment: Only thing I could comment on is number 2: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.powerbi.api.beta.datasets.aspx Under the dataset operations if you delete the dataset it will delete the corresponding uploaded report associated with that dataset

Answer (score 0):

1. **View Number of Rendered Views within a Workspace Collection**:

   Make a `POST` request to the following ARM API with `Content-Length: 0`:

   > [https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroup}/providers/Microsoft.PowerBI/workspaceCollections/{workspaceCollectionName}/billingUsage?api-version=2016-01-29](https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/%7BsubscriptionId%7D/resourceGroups/%7BresourceGroup%7D/providers/Microsoft.PowerBI/workspaceCollections/%7BworkspaceCollectionName%7D/billingUsage?api-version=2016-01-29)
2. **Delete import**:

   Make a `DELETE` request to the following Power BI API:

   > [https://api.powerbi.com/beta/collections/{workspaceCollectionName}/workspaces/{workspaceId}/datasets('{datasetKey}')](https://api.powerbi.com/beta/collections/%7BworkspaceCollectionName%7D/workspaces/%7BworkspaceId%7D/datasets('%7BdatasetKey%7D'))
3. **There is no API for this yet**.

   Consider making the suggestion at https://ideas.powerbi.com/.

Comment: Please update to include the absolute paths for each API call.

Comment: @WallaceBreza Done! Thanks :)